# Django: Foreign key relation depending on choice

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

In Django, is there a way to create the following dynamic relationship between models?

```
 class ClothingMale(models.Model):
     # male specific fields

 class ClothingFemale(models.Model):
     # female specific fields

 class Person(models.Model):
    gender = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
    clothes = models.ForeignKey(???)
```

I am using a ModelForm for Person. The clothes fields inside the form should change dynamically depending on which gender was selected. I am aware of GenericForeignKeys but I was wondering if there is better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it's a question of DB design; I would go for a `PersonClothing` superclass and subclass it with `MalePersonClothing` and `FemalePersonClothing`. The `PersonClothing` superclass would be a Django [abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes); a specific class *useful when you want to put some common information into a number of other models*.

To do it just specify the following option in your model's [meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/):

```
class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

Comment: Ok, but how would I create the dynamic relation? The Foreign Key to Clothing* depends on which gender was selected inside a form at runtime. How would I model this?

Comment: @'Josvic Zammit' yes, it is a ModelForm.

Comment: @mzu The only way I can think of is to specify the gender in advance (a preliminary view); this would lead to different forms (generated per type of model).

Comment: @'Josvic Zammit' ok thanks, I will see if I can get around the problem this way.

Comment: Yes thanks, I basically checked the gender inside my view and used StaffMaleClothesForm and StaffFemaleClothesForm respectively. The models have a OneToOne relationship with the Person but I didn't end up using an abstract model since there were no common fields in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey). This of course has int's down-sides, for exampl you cannot `filter()` on `GenericForeignKey`

Another option is to use [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance), which also has quite a few gotchas.